# Spring Boot App SQLGrammarException with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Spring Boot application works fine locally but it throws SQLGrammarException when it's on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The error message I got on Postman:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errorMessage": "could not prepare statement;  
SQL [select userentity0_.id as col_0_0_ from user_entity userentity0_ where userentity0_.email=? limit ?];  
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement"
}
```

MySQL version on RDS is 8.0.32 and I got `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` part in 'application-prod.yaml':

```
server:
  port: 5000
spring:
  jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://${rds.hostname}:${rds.port}/${rds.db.name}
      username: ${rds.username}
      password: ${rds.password}
```

build.gradle:

```
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32'
```